# How do I create a named range containing non-contiguous cells in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

How do I create a named range containing non-contiguous cells in PHPExcel? Is it even possible? Thanks in advance!

Here's what I did:

```
$objPHPExcel->addNamedRange(
   new PHPExcel_NamedRange('ToggleRange', $activeSheet, 'C4:G5,C9:J10,C14:H15')
);
```

What's happening though is that the named range is only being applied to C4:G5, and not the other cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->addNamedRange( 
    new PHPExcel_NamedRange(
        'MyNamedRange', 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(), 
        'A1:A3,C1:C3,E1:E3'
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working for me .. see above for what I did

Comment: Which writer are you using?

Comment: PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5. It's not supported is it?

Comment: I tried it with PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007. It works awesome! Thanks Mark Baker.

Comment: I'd have to check if Excel BIFF files actually support non-contiguous named ranges, but neither the Excel5 Reader or Writer can handle them even if BIFF does; but OfficeOpenXML and the Excel2007 Reader/Writer do offer a much wider range of features